# Crash when save a photo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, exc-bad-access

I have a strange crash when I save a `UIImage` into camera roll.
I Use this code:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (_originalImage, self,  @selector(photoSaved:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

-(void)photoSaved:(UIImage*)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError*)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo {
if(!error){
    NSLog(@"Photo saved to library!");
} else{
    NSLog(@"Saving failed :(");
}
```

}

This is the Log:

```
2012-11-10 20:43:29.868 MyApp[5012:1a303] Photo saved to library!
```

This is the BT:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x024e509b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3094a576)
frame #0: 0x024e509b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15
frame #1: 0x01b84a8b PhotoLibrary`-[PLUILibraryViewController updateNavigationItemButtons] + 216
frame #2: 0x01b6f054 PhotoLibrary`-[PLLibraryViewController(OverridePoints) updateInterfaceForHasContentChange] + 867
frame #3: 0x01c3c228 PhotoLibrary`-[PLAbstractLibraryViewController _updateHasContent] + 295
frame #4: 0x01c3c7d0 PhotoLibrary`-[PLAbstractLibraryViewController _updateAlbumsWithNotification:] + 681
frame #5: 0x01c3b870 PhotoLibrary`-[PLAbstractLibraryViewController albumListDidChange:] + 272
frame #6: 0x01b84c5b PhotoLibrary`-[PLUILibraryViewController albumListDidChange:] + 236
frame #7: 0x01525a29 Foundation`__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 40
frame #8: 0x0267d855 CoreFoundation`___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 85
frame #9: 0x0267d778 CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 1976
frame #10: 0x0146a234 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotification:] + 121
frame #11: 0x02d217a4 PhotoLibraryServices`-[PLChangeNotificationCenter _postEnqueuedNotifications] + 425
frame #12: 0x02d1f771 PhotoLibraryServices`-[PLChangeNotificationCenter _sendNotificationsForSplitChanges] + 307
frame #13: 0x02d23614 PhotoLibraryServices`-[PLChangeNotificationCenter managedObjectContext:didProcessRemoteContextSave:usingObjectIDs:] + 56
frame #14: 0x02d017cc PhotoLibraryServices`-[PLSharedManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] + 229
frame #15: 0x03edfd2f CoreData`__+[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSCoreDataSPI) _mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:intoContexts:]_block_invoke_4 + 159
frame #16: 0x03e67d03 CoreData`developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 99
frame #17: 0x01af18d9 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 93
frame #18: 0x01af2509 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 353
frame #19: 0x025e9803 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2003
frame #20: 0x025e8d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #21: 0x025e8c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #22: 0x02a2d7d8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 190
frame #23: 0x02a2d88a GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 103
frame #24: 0x00b63626 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1163
frame #25: 0x000026ca MyApp`main + 170 at main.m:16
```

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I hope this makes sense as I'm pretty new to Objective-C, but I recently had a similar problem.  I found out that my image was not being retained when I called the `didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:` method after selecting an image from the Camera Roll.  What worked for me was adding the `withObject:` argument to my method call, as shown here:

`[self performSelector:@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:) withObject:_originalImage];`

This way, the image was retained when the `didFinishSavgngWithError:contextInfo:` method was called where previously it was not.  Again, I'm new to Objective-C but I hope that helps...or at least points you in the right direction.  What would also be helpful is if you could tell me at what point your app crashes (i.e. when you call the imagePicker, when you select an image from the camera roll, etc.).